# Deserializing derived type using DataContractSerializer when derived type is not known beforehand

Tags: c#, deserialization, datacontractserializer

**In Assembly A:**

```
[DataContract]    
        public class Base
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string SomeText { get; set; }
        }
```

**In Assembly B:**

```
internal class Helper
        {
           internal static Base Deserialize(string serializedInstanceOfTypeBase)
    {
                   DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Base));
                    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(serializedInstanceOfTypeBase));
                    return (Base)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
    }
    }
```

**In Assembly C:**

```
[DataContract]    
        public class Derived : Base
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string SomeMoreText { get; set; }
        }
```

If I serialize an instance of type `Derived` and pass it to `Helper.Deserialize()` method, it fails with the `SerializationException`:

> Error in line 1 position 2. Expecting element 'Base' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07'.. Encountered 'Element' 
>   with name 'Derived', namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07'.

**How can I get rid of this issue?**

I am aware of the `KnownType` attribute, but at the time of coding in assembly A and B, I am absolutely not aware of its derived types. So I cannot use that solution.

Design of my product is more complex which I cannot post here entirely. `Helper.Desrialize()` method just gets a `string` argument. There is no way (at present at least) for assembly A or B, to know about derived types of `Base` class, even at runtime.

Assembly B references assembly A. But A & B cannot reference assembly C.

I am using C# 4.0. It's ok if the solution you provide is NOT using `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: I don't know about a out-of-the-box solution. I know in my experience when I had a wide variety of types, I would actually double-serialize my content with type information. That is, I would have a `SerializedObject` which would contain full type information (assembly name, full class name), along with its serialized XML string. My data transfer layer would strongly type itself against `SerializedObject`, grab a runtime reference to the type (say via `Type.GetType`), then deserialize the XML data accordingly via an XmlSerializer.

Comment: You mean 'Base' class is in 'Assembly A' and 'Derived' class is in 'Assembly C'? If this is so then I think this is the problem. The Data Contracts should be defined in same assembly. The DataContracts should not be splitted across assemblies.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need both:

- Pass a collection of KnownTypes into your deserializer (as mentioned above)
- Tell the deserializer not to check the type (use `verifyObjectName`parameter):

  ```
  return (Base)serializer.ReadObject(reader, false);
  ```

see details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the types *at runtime* ? If so, a simple approach might be just:

```
List<Type> knownTypes = ...; // now that you know what to expect
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(
    typeof(Base), knownTypes);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very helpful but I have added more details to the question. I should have added those details before. Note that `Helper` class is in different assembly and it's not `public`. Also, `Deserialize` method just gets any string value.